# Branch policy on Google cloud source repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

How to set the branch policy in Google cloud source repository, developers not allowed to push the code to the master branch, also how to create a Pull Request.

Comment: Which error messages are you getting? What have you tried? Have you read the docs and there is something that is not working as expected?

Comment: I haven't got any error message, I didn't find any link related to the branch policy on source repository

Answer (score 7):

As you've mentioned, there is no documentation to accomplish this approach of not allowing someone to push to the `master` or in general to any branch like in [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-branch-restrictions).

Actually, the security setting only admitted by Cloud Source Repositories are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/granting-users-access) but the permissions are basically "You can write to a repo", "You can view the repo" or "You can't access the repo" and that's all.

Regarding the Pull Request, I think this is also not possible with Cloud Source Repositories, then, I would suggest to go with GitHub if those settings are important for your workflow and then you can [mirror](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository) the repo from GitHub to CloudSource repositories.

Finally, there are already some Feature Requests for this two specific questions, [Pull Requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/77815817) and [Permissions at branch level](https://issuetracker.google.com/79218171). You may want to upvote those Feature Requests and add a comment.